# Cannot run h1 xterm on mininet (Diplay not found)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, mininet

I am trying to run wireshark on h1 node on mininet.
I have downloaded and imported the mininet VM
I was successfully able to ssh into the mininet VM from my host computer.

When I try running `h1 xterm` or `xterm h1` or `h1 wireshark &` on mininet I get on of the following errors:

- Can't connect to display %s
- Could not connect to display
- Display not found

Here are all the things I have tried:

- setting `$ DISPLAY=:0.0   $ export DISPLAY` and then
- sudo -E mn
- using `ssh -X mininet@192.168.56.102`

I always end up getting the same error or no response.`enter code here`

Comment: Are you running this on your local machine or are you using ssh? Have you setup your DISPLAY variable correctly on the host and can you verify this.  Have you checked if the DISPLAY variable is set on the mininet host you are trying to work with, e.g., h1?

Comment: Yes echoing DISPLAY on h1 doesn't print anything.

Comment: There is your issue, h1 is not configured to have a display, make sure you do this first, then if you get an authentication issue you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319171/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication-in-mininet/67489444#67489444